# How to extract string after some character

Tags: python, string

I need to extract a known portion from a given string.

```
Ex:

test_str="http://localhost:8080/course-single.html"
```

I need to extract "**course-single**" from above string. What is the most easiest way to do that?

Comment: If you are using python 3 can't you just do `test[22:35]`

Comment: @O.KOO Why would you want to hardcode this?

Comment: Kit did not say he is going to perform extraction on multiple URLs. Kit simply says he needs "course-single" from above string. If is one time then why not hardcode it?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO I don't think that is the right approach to take, no matter what OP says. It leads to less maintainable, one time use code, that'll need be harder to change. I don't care how many people agree with you, that's just something I'll never get behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain a couple of `str.split` calls:

```
test = "http://localhost:8080/course-single.html"

test.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.')[0]
# 'course-single'
```

---

**Details**
First, get everything after the last `/`:

```
temp = test.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
temp
# 'course-single.html'
```

Next, get everything before the `.html` portion:

```
temp = temp.split('.')
temp
# ['course-single', 'html']

temp[0]
# 'course-single'
```

Comment: If you are interested, you can append the `urllib` stuff I mentioned in my answer and I'll just delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python 3, use the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) module, then trim out the parts you don't want from the resulting "path" you want:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> url_str = "http://localhost:8080/course-single.html"
>>> urlparse(url_str).path.split('.')[0][1:]
'course-single'
```

Details:

`urlparse(url_str)` will yield:

```
ParseResult(
    scheme='http', netloc='localhost:8080', path='/course-single.html', 
    params='', query='', fragment=''
)
```

So, you extract the `path`:

`urlparse(url_str).path`: to get: `'/course-single.html'`

Then you need to remove the parts you are not interested in, so `split` on the `.`, which will give you `['/course-single', 'html']`. So, just access the first item (`[0]`), remove the first slash with `[1:]` slice and that gives you your final result of `course-single`.

## Multiple slashes

If you have a longer url, and you need that last part, then you can do the following, and it should work for whatever length url you provide:

```
>>> url_str = "http://localhost:8080/a/b/c/course-single.html"
>>> urlparse(url_str)
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='localhost:8080', path='/a/b/c/course-single.html', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse(url_str).path.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.')[0]
'course-single'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
word = re.search('\d/(.*?)\.html', test)
print word.groups()[0]
```

Output:

```
course-single
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
test="http://localhost:8080/course-single.html"
str = test[test.find('8080/') + 5: test.find('.html')]
print str
```

Details:
`test.find('8080/')` - find place where `8080/` string is located ( + 5 because we only have interested in string comes next in line ).
`test.find('.html')` - find where `.html` located.
`test[test.find('8080/') + 5: test.find('.html')]` - get string between this 2 located strings.

Comment: added comment on the post.